# Does python with wsgi (uwsgi) under nginx have some small default cache?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

In my small web-site I feel need to make some data widely available, to avoid exchanging with database for every request made. E.g. this could be the list of current users show in the bottom of every page or the time of last update of ranking.

The stuff works in Python (Flask) running upon nginx + uwsgi ([this](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx/) docker image).

I wonder, do I have some small cache or shared memory for keeping such information "out of the box", or I need to take care of explicitly setting up some dedicated cache? Or perhaps some thing like this is provided by nginx?

*alternatively I still can use database for it has its own cache I think, anyway*

Sorry if question seems to be naive/silly - for I come from java world (where things a bit different as we serve all requests with one fat instance of java application) - and have some difficulty grasping what powers does wsgi/uwsgi provide. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, nginx has cache:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

But for flask cacheing you also have options:

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/caching/

Comment: Thanks for this ready list of options. Do I understand correctly that flask caching requires (perhaps, besides SimpleCache) setting up the cache application (redis or memcached)?

Comment: That's one way to go yes @RodionGorkovenko, you would need to setup redis or memcached if you want to use them.

Comment: Thanks :) That's the point. It seems that for storing few values redis and memcached would be overkill, while I can't clearly understand is it correct to use SimpleCache in uwsgi setup :)

Comment: No simplecache is for development only. If you think redis/memcache is overkill then nginx caching might be for you -- you're already using nginx

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [caching section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/caching/) from Flask docs?

It literally says:

> Flask itself does not provide caching for you, but Werkzeug, one of the libraries it is based on, has some very basic cache support
>
> You create a cache object once and keep it around, similar to how Flask objects are created. If you are using the development server you can create a SimpleCache object, that one is a simple cache that keeps the item stored in the memory of the Python interpreter:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache
cache = SimpleCache()
```

-- UPDATE --

Or you could solve on the frontend side storing data in the web browser local storage.

If there's nothing in the local storage you call the DB, else you use the information from local storage rather than making db call.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've seen this but I'm not sure I understand how it behaves in uwsgi setup. Docs say SimpleCache is for single process and "may not be 100% thread safe"... If uwsgi runs in 2 processes and both will create dedicated copy of the cache, which is then used in say 100 requests - this is ok. If they will use single instance - or if it is created for every request - probably it is not what I should use...

Comment: did you try local storage?@RodionGorkovenko

Comment: I'm afraid local storage is not of much use. See, for example I add in the page template some counter, like "5 users are online, 30 problems were solved today". These are data which are going to be shown on every page, but I don't want recalculate them on every load and they are the same for all users (and people who brows without logging in). Cache accessible from all requests/processes seems like good option...